# Filter text in vim using scala

Tags: scala, vim, intellij-idea

Suppose you have the following text content in vim editor:

```
a   b   c
d   e   f
a   b   c
d   e   f
a   b   c
d   e   f
a   b   c
d   e   f
a   b   c
d   e   f
```

And you visually select all and do  `!tail -n 1`, then the text is pipe through the `tail` command and only the last line is left.

Now suppose I have a snippet in scala like this:

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
    println("Hello")
}
HelloWorld.main(Array(""))
```

How can I filter it so that it becomes "Hello"?

The same technique can be applied in intellij with ideavim enabled.

I have tried `!scala` but the result is a mess of course:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> object HelloWorld extends App {
     |     println("Hello")
     | }
defined object HelloWorld

scala> HelloWorld.main(Array(""))
Hello

scala> :quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
! xargs -0 scala -e
```

`scala -e`  executes its argument as Scala code, and `xargs -0` turns the piped input into an argument for the given command.

Comment: Cool. This works in vim, but not in intellij with ideavim.